# Joint probability function question

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $f(x,y) = y^{-1}e^{-x/y}e^{-y}$ with $x,y >0$ and $0$ elsewhere.

Find $\mathbb{P}(\{X>1\} \mid \{Y = y\})$, $y >0$.

My attempt:

$$\mathbb{P}\{X>1, Y =y\} = \iint_{(1, +\infty) \times \{y\}} f(x,y) dxdy$$

And the integral gives 0 because I integrate over a line, so the probability is 0.

But I must have something wrong, but can't tell exactly what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a conditional probability problem, and you had better figure out the conditional density $f_{X|Y}$ at first, which is defined as
$$
f_{X|Y}(x,y)=\frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_{X,Y}(x,y){\rm d}x}.
$$
Note that
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_{X,Y}(x,y){\rm d}x=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{y}e^{-x/y}e^{-y}{\rm d}x=-e^{-y}\int_{x=0}^{x=\infty}e^{-x/y}{\rm d}\left(-x/y\right)=e^{-y}.
$$
Thus
$$
f_{X|Y}(x,y)=\frac{1}{y}e^{-x/y}.
$$
Thanks to this conditional density,
$$
\mathbb{P}(X>1|Y=y)=\int_1^{\infty}f_{X|Y}(x,y){\rm d}x=\int_1^{\infty}\frac{1}{y}e^{-x/y}{\rm d}x=-\int_{x=1}^{x=\infty}e^{-x/y}{\rm d}\left(-x/y\right)=e^{-1/y}.
$$

Comment: Thanks. Where exactly do I make a mistake?

Comment: @Math_QED: $\mathbb{P}(A|B)$ means the probability of $A$ given the information $B$, i.e., $\mathbb{P}(A|B)=\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)/\mathbb{P}(B)$. In your way, $\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)=0$, which is correct; but this is not the answer. The correct answer is this $0$ divided by $\mathbb{P}(B)$, which is another $0$. Thus your method would fail.

Comment: Ah that explains it. I didn't bother to check the denominator. Thanks!

Comment: @Math_QED: My pleasure :-)